# How to count the set $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've seen this http://www.homeschoolmath.net/teaching/rational-numbers-countable.php
 which only counts the positive numbers, but how can also count (or order) the non positive ones?

Comment: Think about the [Grande Hotel of Hilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel#Infinitely_many_new_guests).

Comment: Imagine a table of "negative ones" put behind the table of positive ones (as shown in your link). Modify the "steps" so at each positive rational $r$ you step $-r$ "into the table to negative one" and do the same step as decribed for positive table, and then you come back to positive one, and do another step. Repeat these and you will count all of them essentially

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

$f(x)=
 \cases
 {
  1                           &x=0\\
  2^{n(x)}\cdot3^{d(x)}       &x>0\\
  2^{n(x)}\cdot3^{d(x)}\cdot5 &x<0\\
 }
$

Where:

- $n(x)$ is the numerator of the simplest form of $|x|$
- $d(x)$ is the denominator of the simplest form of $|x|$

Of course, you can replace $[2,3,5]$ with any other set of unique prime numbers.